# Firebase provided authentication credentials are invalid

Tags: firebase

The Firebase project I was working on was deleted and a new project has been created. I now need to use the credentials for the new project, which I have done. I generated a new Service Account Key from the google cloud console and replaced the old Service Account Key with thew new one. I replace the database(URL) with the URL to the new project as well. I updated my .firebaserc file with the new project. Still I am getting the error:

`FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials for the app named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid. This usually indicates your app was not initialized correctly. Make sure the "credential" property provided to initializeApp() is authorized to access the specified "databaseURL" and is from the correct project.`

I updated my config file with the new Service Account Key, updated the props passed to firebase.initializeApp, updated the .firebaserc file, am I missing something else I'm missing?

I only have an editor role for the project, and I generated the Service Account Key using google cloud. Do I need a owner role to obtain a Service Account Key that works?

```js
{
    "serviceAccount": {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "new-project",
      "private_key_id": <SOME KEY>,
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nSOME-KEY",
      "client_email": "new-project@new-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "client_id": <SOME KEY>,
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/new-project%40new-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      }
    }
```

```js
firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://new-project.firebaseio.com',
});
```

```js
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "new-project"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the entire, minimal code.  In particular, what's `firebase`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the JavaScript SDK (for web) vs the Admin/Node SDK (for server side). Service Accounts are for the server side authentication. For web, you want to use firebase authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Right, you need to have owner privileges on the project to generate a Service Account Key with the right permissions.